# Sort method is not working with useState() in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, use-state

I put `onClick()` event on element and try to change on UI new data but it fails. `podaciLjubimci` in `console.log()` returns me **new state with new data** based on `countLike` but **nothing happens on UI**.

Why does array change with new data and send me in `console.log()` but `setState()` did not render component?

**Code:**

```
const [podaciLjubimci, setState] = useState([
  { id: 1, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 1, },
  { id: 2, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 12, },
  { id: 3, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 12, },
  { id: 4, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 5, },
  { id: 5, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 2, },
  { id: 6, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 7, },
  { id: 7, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 22, },
  { id: 8, naziv: "naziv", pol: "Muski", starost: "junuor", mesto: "Beograd", isLike: false, countLike: 9, },
]);

const nepopularni = () => {
  setState(podaciLjubimci.sort((a, b) => a.countLike - b.countLike));
  console.log("sort", podaciLjubimci);
};
```

Comment: So i need copy of array like this: const newData = [...podaciLjubimci] and then sort that data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the below code:

```
setState(podaciLjubimci.sort((a, b) => a.countLike - b.countLike))
```

you are **mutating** the state data because [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns the sorted (*same reference, not new*) array. And that's the reason your console log shows you sorted data but [it does not re-render the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

To sort the state data without mutating the original data, you need to **shallow copy the array** before sorting.

**An example:**

```
setState([].concat(podaciLjubimci).sort((a, b) => a.countLike - b.countLike))
```

PS: There are many ways to shallow copy the array. For example, you can use `.slice()`, spread syntax, `concat()`, or `.map()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858879/how-to-fix-my-sorting-function-in-my-crud-table?noredirect=1#comment119942163_67858879 I have a similar question

Comment: @max I have already seen your question. You need to shallow copy the array before sorting (like shown in this asnwer).

Comment: oh I think I understand
customerList.map(val,key)
                       .sort() 
right?

Comment: omg it does I cant believe that was it ive been trying to fix this for days

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you create a copy of the array before making any array operation

```
const copyArray = [...yourArray]
```

then perform any array operation

official reference
https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#making-other-changes-to-an-array