# How to fix my sorting function in my crud table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

frontend code

```
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const displaySortedCustomers = () => {
    customerList.sort(function (a, b) {
      setCustomerList(customerList);
      return b - a;
    });
  };
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      const my_serial = key + pageNumber * customersPerPage;

      return (
        <tr>
          {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      */}
          <td>{my_serial + 1}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

<div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      {/*}
                      <th>S/N</th>
              */}
                      <th>S/N</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th onClick={displaySortedCustomers}>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
```

So I have a table by drawing reference to my frontend code, I added an onClick method to the table column "contacted" to run the function displaySortedCustomers but it does not sort? How to change the code?
I need the table to sort one first click , then sort in reverse order 2nd click, sort back to unsorted order in third click.

Comment: Why did you put `setCustomerList(customerList);` inside `customerList.sort(function (a, b) {
      setCustomerList(customerList);
      return b - a;
    });`

Comment: Furthermore, what are `a` and `b` in your `customerList.sort` function, Are they numbers? Otherwise, how would `b - a` return a numeric value?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath and derp on then what should I do instead

Comment: At first glance, two things. 1) You're not telling it _how_ to sort - you're telling it to sort the same every time. So you need to save the sort state (ie 'asc', desc') and then base your sort on that. 2) You're trying to set the state _within_ the sort compare function. You should be doing this after everything has been sorted.

Comment: @Andy 1) Im sorting on Contacted Column, 2) so I need create a new state?
const [sortedCustomerList, setSortedCustomerList]?

Comment: @AjeetShah if I use a react table what will happen to my existing table

Comment: Try `setCustomerList([].concat(customerList).sort((a, b) => b.contacted - a.contacted))` inside your function.

Comment: I have to return something right? b-a ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233381/discussion-between-max-and-ajeet-shah).

Comment: @max, I've provided a detailed answer that should hopefully help you out.

Comment: @AjeetShah Hi Ajeet I added
const displaySort = () => {
    setCustomerList(
      [].concat(customerList).sort((a, b) => b.contacted - a.contacted)
    );
  };

then an onClick method on the contacted header to run displaySort on click but doesn't work

Comment: @AjeetShah https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-table-sorting-qroke

Comment: its impossible to create the sandbox as my table pulls data from backend

Comment: @AjeetShah I have GitHub link, message me and I send it to you

Comment: @max No problem. Then I will check your sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example.

1. Use state to hold the sort order.
2. Ensure the [sort compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) is correct (a < b, not a - b).
3. Change the order state after updating the data state.

Note, that once sorted, you can only sort in the other direction - you can't return to an "unsorted order" as mentioned in your question unless you keep a copy of that data somewhere and replace the data in state with that data. But that doesn't seem necessary.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// Do an inital sort of the array
// We're no longer passing in the data to the component
const customers = ['Bob', 'Andy', 'Joe', 'Sam'].sort();

// Mocked API call that returns the data after 2 seconds
function fakeApiCall() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(customers), 2000);
  });
}

function Example() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
  
  // Set the state for the order, initially to 'asc'
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState('asc');

  useEffect(() => {

    // Call the API (Axios) for the data, then set the state
    fakeApiCall().then(data => setData(data));
  }, []);

  // A function that takes an order type
  // and returns a new function to use with `sort`
  // Note we're using less than and greater than
  // rather than "minus" to determine the sort order
  function comparator(order) {
    return function (a, b) {
      return order === 'asc' ? b.localeCompare(a) : a.localeCompare(b);
    }
   }

  // Sets the state of the sorted data, and then set the order state
  function handleSort() {
    setData(data.sort(comparator(sortOrder)));
    setSortOrder(curr => curr === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
  }

  // Add rows to the table using the data
  function getRows() {
    return data.map(name => <tr><td>{name}</td></tr>);
  }

  function getArrow() {
    if (sortOrder === 'asc') return '↑';
    return '↓';
  }

  // Make sure you check to see if the data has loaded
  if (!data.length) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th onClick={handleSort}>Customers {getArrow()}</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {getRows()}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
th:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #dfdfdf; }
tr { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: For const [ data, setData ] = useState(customers); can I use [] instead of customers? Also I have a copy of the unsorted data in customerList how can I render it on the 3rd click?

Comment: @max, sure, this is only a _very_ simple example of how _sorting works with state_. How you initialise your data is up to you.

Comment: I have a state with my original data
```
const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

can I replace customers with customerList and how do I render the customerList on 3rd click?

Comment: See my edits @max. I've added a fake API call in a `useEffect` and some code that checks to see if the data is loaded or not.

Comment: <tbody>
        {getRows()}
      </tbody>

I can't add this in because I have another function in body which is displayCustomers, this loads the original current unsorted data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233386/discussion-between-max-and-andy).

Comment: @max, as I said __this is only an example__. You need to extrapolate any relevant information and use it to _inform_ your code. I don't really expect you to copy and paste everything I wrote.

Comment: Yes but how can I run 2 functions at one time? one displayCustomers another sorted  customers function?

Comment: I tried using customerList.sort() but it returns unsorted